# control print queue with jpdfprint

Tags: java, printing

I'm working on a web application with a printer and I need to make a print using a printer queue, my question is ¿can you control print queue with jpdfprint ?

link of the site [pdfprint](http://www.qoppa.com/pdfprint)

thanks!